# How to change an int value by user input?

Tags: java

For the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Convert
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter the duration of the event in seconds: ");
  int duration = keyboard.nextInt();

int days;
int hours;
int minutes;
int seconds;
```

What I need is, if user inputs 
- <60 seconds, it will add onto seconds
- >60 seconds, it will add onto minutes
- >3600 seconds, it will add onto hours
- >86400 seconds, it will add onto days.

So for example,
if the user enters the value 3750 (= 3600 + 120 + 30), the output
should be:

The event lasts 0 days 1 hours 2 minutes and 30 seconds

Comment: Okay, so what went wrong in your first attempt?

Comment: You seem to have some formatting issues.  Your indentation may be a bit off and you seem to be missing the end of your code block.  Could you provide enough to fill out that missing curly brace?

Comment: We need abit more code.  This should be feasible to do

Comment: @DennisMeng I actually haven't attempted anything just yet. I just don't really know how to start it. All I would like is maybe a head start and to see what I should be doing to make this code work.

Comment: @user2959072 Start it first; you might get farther along than you think. Throw something together and test it out. If it doesn't work, try to find out why it doesn't work on your own, and see if you can use that to fix your first attempt. If *after* that, you're still stuck, show us what you've tried, and we can give tips from there.

Comment: @Adel This is an example i got off an exam sample worksheet. It is asking me to complete the code. I'm fairly new to this coding and would love if somebody could just maybe give me an example of what could come next I've tried for statements and if statements but it didn't seem to work out

Comment: @DennisMeng I have, and currently still am trying to work things out but it's not happening haha. I'm getting a little frustrated :p

Comment: @user2959072 Then try to narrow what you have down to a manageable size, and show us an example of why it's not working (code + input + output + expected output). Not only does it look better, this means that you also get to keep any part of your code that you did right the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter the duration of the event in seconds: ");
  int duration = keyboard.nextInt();

    int days;
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;

    days = duration / 86400;
    hours = duration % 86400 / 3600;
    minutes = duration % 86400 % 3600 / 60;
    seconds = duration % 86400 % 3600 % 60;
    System.out.println("The event lasts "+days+" days "+hours+" hours "+minutes+" minutes and "+seconds+" seconds");
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this might sound noobish but what does the % operator do exactly?

Comment: @user2959072 At least in this case, you can think of `a % b` as "the remainder you get when you divide `a` by `b`"

Comment: % or modulus will give you the remainder after divide. for example, 3 % 2 = 1, 20 % 3= 2, 5 % 60=5

Answer (score 0):

```
public void seperateDuration(int dur)
{
    if(dur >= 86400) //checks if duration is greater than 1 day
    {
        while(dur >= 86400) //decreases 86400 seconds from duration for each day and adds 1 to day counter
        {
            dur-=86400;
            days++;
        }
    }
    if(dur >= 3600) //decreases 3600 seconds from duration for each hour and adds 1 to hour counter

    {
        while(dur >= 3600)
        {
            dur-= 3600;
            hours++;
        }
    }
    if(dur >= 60) //decreases 60 seconds from duration for each minute and adds 1 to day minute

    {
       while(dur >= 60)
       {
           dur -= 60;
           minutes++;
       }
    }
    seconds += dur; //adds remaining duration to seconds (will be less than 60)
}
```